# searching for an option to compare data of an sql file with a txt file in csv form

Tags: mysql, sql, text, phpmyadmin, mariadb

I got a Problem, cause I'm totally new to sql and have to kinda learn it in an internship. So I had to import huge txt files into a database in phpmyadmin (took me for ever but managed it with load data infile). Now my task is to find a way to control if the data of the tables is the same as the data of the given txt files. 
Is there any possibility to do so ?

Comment: Please clarify what `control if the data of the tables is the same as the data of the given txt files` entails.

Comment: like if the lines are exactly the same

Comment: If you haven't changed them, then they are the same.  What is the perceived threat?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried exporting the data through phpMyAdmin using a different file format instead of .sql? phpMyAdmin gives you several choices including CSV, OpenOffice spreadsheets. That would make your compare easier. You could use Excel, sort the data and you'd have a quicker compare.

Answer (score 0):

the best way to do so is to load, and then extract. 
Compare your extract with the original file.

Another way could be to count the number of line in both table and file. And extract few lines, and verify that they both exists. This is less precise.

But this has nothing to do with SQL. It is just a test logic.

Comment: the problem is by extracting the sql file it slightly changes the way the colums are seperatet, compared to the txt file.

Comment: and ? dont you know how to use excel ? You have tons of tools that can help you with that.

Comment: not sure if excel will work fine with a 1,5Gb file on with excel only operating at 32bit.

Comment: Basically, if you use the proper tools to ingest your data and you dont have any error, it means your loading is ok. You dont have to control furthermore.